# How to prove price of Asian option under geometric averaging is cheaper than a European call?

Tags: black-scholes, derivatives

This was an exam question at Cambridge University.

> Let $S_t = S_0 \exp \left(\sigma W_t + (r-\dfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2) \right)$ and a bank account returns a continuously-compounded rate of interest $r$. Consider the derivative which pays
>
> $Y = (\exp(T^{-1}\int^T_0\log(S_u)\text{d}u) - K)^+$ at time T.
>
> What is the time-0 price for this derivative, and show it is less than the price of a European call.

The price of this, if I am not wrong, is

$S_0\exp(-\dfrac{1}{2}(r+\sigma^2/6)T) N(d_2) - Ke^{-rT}F(-d_1)$

where $d_1 = \log(K/S_0-1/2(r-\sigma^2)T)/(\sigma\sqrt{T/3})$ and $d_2 = -d_1+\sigma\sqrt{T/3}$.

I don't see how this is less than the European call.

Comment: Hi, the pay-off that you describe here is that of an [Asian option](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_option) with geometric averaging. Maybe I find time to formulate an answer later.

Comment: @Richard thank you

Comment: @Richard *nudge* if you cba, a reference would also do.

Comment: The volatility of this product is sigma*sqrt(T/3), which is smaller than that of the European option sigma*sqrt(T). Thus the price of it should be lower than that of the European option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- first - a nice and short note for the calculation can be found [here](http://financelab.nctu.edu.tw/Students/chiu/geometric.pdf).
- second: what do they mean by cheaper? The pay-off is different - so what can we compare. The only meaning is that if the stock has an implied volatility of $\sigma$ then the continuously sampled Asian option has an implied vol of $\sigma/3$ (check your $d_1$ there is something wrong in the numerator). So we can say that given the same moneyness the Asian option looks like a standard European option but with a third of its implied vol. Thus the Asian is cheaper.

Another reference [Theory of Continuously-sampled Asian Option pricing](http://www.cb.cityu.edu.hk/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/progress?id=gzyuLZQcC5).

Comment: The 2nd ref does not open on my iPad. Will try again on a computer later. Thank you

Comment: Google the title and you will get a download link. I can not post the direct link.

Comment: Links are dead :(

Comment: @BobJansen this is a pity. I didn't want to recite the content back then. A search points me to https://www.math.kth.se/matstat/seminarier/reports/M-exjobb12/120412a.pdf do you think I should replace the links ... or internet search such as "geometric asian option" for such a well known topic is enough?

Comment: Ideally an answer is self-contained. Your second note still answers this question but I believe it's better with a more elaborate explanation of the calculation.